# Как реализовать вариативные картинки не в товаре, а именно в публикации (посте)

Tags: изображения, woocommerce, веб-дизайн

Есть задача: созать ряд публикаций (страниц) с продукцией разного цвета. Как сделать аналог вариаций изображений как в product, но только для некоммерческих публикаций (не в виде товара)?
пример: https://www.toyota.ua/new-cars/yaris-cross/overview.YB.040.4b06bb28-83a4-4559-b62c-8b9446feabb8

Т.е. при віборе определенных опций (цвет и элементы дизайна) подтягивалось конкретное изображение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите, что у вас не получается, для этого нажмите [edit]. Если вы ищете алгоритм или подходящую библиотеки, то так и напишите.